# Firemonkey application developed through RAD Studio 10.0 is crashing on iOS 7.1?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I have an application to which I have released on http://www.diawi.com/index.php for the testers, but it isn't launching on IOS 7.1 devices. I have set the minimum deployment target as IOS 7.1, but my base sdk is IOS 9. It is launching fine on iOS 8 and iOS 9. what could be the reason? Is there no support for iOS versions less than 8.0 on Delphi 10 Seattle?

Answer (score 2):

Per Embarcadero's documentation:

[Adding a Mac OS X or iOS SDK](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Adding_a_Mac_OS_X_or_iOS_SDK)

> Notes:
>
> - RAD Studio does not support versions of the iOS SDK lower than 8.0.
> - iOS applications built with a given SDK version may only run on that version or later versions of iOS. For example, an application built with version 9 of the iOS SDK might crash on a device running iOS 8.

Based on that, the following documentation seems to have a contradiction:

[FireMonkey Platform Prerequisites](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites)

> The following iOS devices are supported:
>
> - iPod Touch, iPhone, or iPad
> - **iOS 7**
> - iOS 8
> - iOS 9
>
> For iOS application development, you need to have installed on the Mac:
>
> - **iOS 8 SDK or iOS 9 SDK**
> - Xcode 6 or Xcode 7, see Installing Xcode

This suggests they support iOS 7 devices, but do not support the iOS 7 SDK.

However, there are Delphi forum discussions that claim you can use xCode 6.4 and the iOS 8.4 SDK to target iOS 7 and 8 in Delphi Seattle.  And there is [this Embarcadero blog post](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/paserver-hotfix-for-rad-studio-10-seattle-ios-9-and-os-x-el-capitan) that supports that claim, and points to a [Hotfix for Seattle](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30398) that allows Delphi to use the iOS 9 SDK to target iOS 7 and 8.

Do you have that hotfix installed?